# How to edit row of Telerik MVC grid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I am trying to edit a cell's innerText property. The text is shown in the table but the problem is that the row isn't being marked as updated, so when I press my "Save Changes" button the update method doesn't get this row (in the list of rows to update).

I am trying to use this method (updateRow) but so far it has been unsuccessful:

```
var grid = ("#grid").data("tGrid");
var rowToUpdate = grid.data[0];
rowToUpdate.quantity = 4;
grid.updateRow(rowToUpdate);
```

When the method is called I get the following exception:

> "object does not support this property or method".

in the source of telerik. Does anyone know how to mark a row as updated? Or a better way to update the value of cell in row?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, `updateRow` expects you to supply the actual row element (wrapped by jQuery), and not the object acting as the data.

Comment: I saw example using rowUpdate method with an object in telerik site: [link](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#updateRow)

Comment: ah, i hadn't noticed that before.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the client-side method [`updateRow`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#updateRow) to force updating. The key is selecting the table row you wish to update, as indicated in their example (of course, you don't have to use their `$('#Grid .t-grid-edit-row')` selector; you can use any selector, so long as it selects the row you wish to update). I believe that your modifying of the cell's `innerHTML`/`innerText` to communicate the new value is how its done.